# Razorpay Capture PHP error

Tags: php, razorpay

```
include 'razorpay/Razorpay.php';

use Razorpay\Api\Api;

$api = new Api('Keyid', 'Keysecret');

$payment = $api->payment->fetch('pay_8qNw3E4GvwEEbx')->capture(array('amount' => 1000));
```

I get:

> HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Format your question properly and show the full code not just part of it.

Comment: That's the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be sending your capture request with amount set to **1000**, whereas the authorized amount of the payment itself is **100000**. This causes a mismatch, and is the reason you are getting an error.

You will have received an HTTP 4xx response code for this, as is expected.

**Note that all Razorpay APIs, including the [Capture API](https://docs.razorpay.com/docs/v1paymentsidcapture), require the amount to be expressed in paise and not rupees.**